# Classification of group extension.

Tags: semidirect-product, direct-product

Direct product, semidirect product and central extension are different types of group extensions. Is there any other type? If there is, can you please give an example with a small finite group?

Comment: Yes, there are other types, like non-central extensions, non-split extension, etc. Many examples can be found at this site. Have you searched already?

Comment: Yes, thank you!